# What are docker layers in union mount?

Tags: docker

in The docker book we read

> In the Docker world, however, the root filesystem stays in read-only mode, and Docker
>   takes advantage of a union mount to add more read-only filesystems onto the root filesystem.

[image: picture about docker layers from The docker book]

I want to ask: what is every layer (executed command from Dockerfile) after base image: image or filesystem? (If Image in what sense, if filesystem how can individual command be filesystem ). Is container as a whole also and Image?